# Google Maps - using geocoder to get long/lat with javascript

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I'm trying to get longitude and latitude values from the google maps api with an address, however it doesn't seem to be returning any value. Is there a problem with my syntax?

```
var point = GClientGeocoder.getLatLng('1600 Pennsylvania Avenue NW Washington, DC 20500');
alert(point);
```

Comment: Do you get any error messages?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This works (provided you have the correct API key, subject to the 2500 requests/day rate limit):

```
address_string = '1600 Pennsylvania Avenue NW Washington, DC 20500';
geocoder = new GClientGeocoder();
geocoder.getLatLng(
    address_string,
    function(point) {
        if (point !== null) {
            alert(point); // or do whatever else with it
        } else {
            // error - not found, over limit, etc.
        }
    }
);
```

You seem to be calling a function of `GClientGeocoder`, where you need to create a `new GClientGeocoder()` and call *its* function.

Answer (score 38):

It seems like you're using v2 of Google Maps; if you're interested in using v3 (since Google has officially deprecated version 2), you could do something like this:

```
var mygc = new google.maps.Geocoder();
mygc.geocode({'address' : '1600 Pennsylvania Avenue NW Washington, DC 20500'}, function(results, status){
    console.log( "latitude : " + results[0].geometry.location.lat() );
    console.log( "longitude : " + results[0].geometry.location.lng() );
});
```

It's similar to the other examples except:

- You call **new google.maps.Geocoder()** instead of GClientGeocoder()
- You pass in an object with an 'address' property, instead of the string by itself
- The results is a JSON object, which means you have to access lat/lng a little differently

The [Google API docs](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/reference.html#GeocoderResult) have more detail for v3. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

Try it like:

```
geocoder = new GClientGeocoder();
point = geocoder.getLatLng(address)
```